# Inner sum of a range of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

By inner sum I mean e.g. the inner sum of 123 is equal to 1+2+3=6

Say I have two numbers indicating a (inclusive) range, a and b, which I get from standard input, and I want to add the inner sum of all numbers in that range. My solution:

```
a, b = sys.stdin.readline().split()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
s = 0
for x in range(a, b+1):
    t = str(x)
    s = s + sum([int(i) for i in t])
print(s)
```

Works fine. But is there a faster way? I feel like the usage of list-comprehension is quite slow, so I would like some input here.

Comment: are you operating on range input boundaries OR numeric string?

Comment: if a and b is big enough use digit dp ! Complexity will be length(a+b)*9*2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a and b is large enough, you can use the following approach. If maximum length of a and b is n (number of digit in a or b), then complexity is O(n*10*n).
So if the number(a or b) is 10^9, then complexity will be about (9*9*10)=810

I first calculate the summation of digits of all numbers upto b (summation(b)) and after that I find the summation of digits of all numbers  upto a-1(summation(a-1)).Then I calculated the desired result through summation(b)-summation(a-1).

```
import sys
def power(x):
    po=1
    for i in range(x):
        po=po*10
    return po
def summation(x):
    s=str(x)
    le=len(s)
    res=0
    carry=0
    for i in range(le):
        c=int(s[i])
        rem=le-i-1
        for j in range(c):
           res=res+((carry+j)*power(rem)+45*(rem)*power(rem-1))
        carry+=c
    res+=carry
    return res


a, b = sys.stdin.readline().split()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
s = 0

#Bruteforce
for x in range(a, b+1):
    t = str(x)
    s = s + sum([int(i) for i in t])

#Optimized
res=summation(b)-summation(a-1)

print(res,s)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. Just had to fix the edge-cases of a=0 and such.

Answer (score 1):

note that if the most significant digit `msd` does not change; the sum will just increase by one and there is no need to recalculate it. also if the `msd` changes, the sum is just equal to `msd`:

```
s = 0
a = 12
b = 37

last_msd = None
last_sum = None
for x in range(a, b + 1):
    t = str(x)
    msd = int(t[0])
    if last_msd is None:
        last_msd = msd
        last_sum = sum(int(i) for i in t)
    elif msd != last_msd:
        last_msd = msd
        last_sum = msd
    else:
        last_sum += 1
    s += last_sum
print(s)  # 169
```

note that there is no need to create a `list` inside `sum`; a generator expression will do.

you might find something more efficient on oeis: [A007953](https://oeis.org/A007953) (sum of digits) or [A037123](https://oeis.org/A037123) sum of digits accumulated.

Comment: if a and b is  about 10^15??

Comment: for now the question was to just speed it up; not reduce the complexity...

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links. Much appreciated. Also, yes ofc. I know that strings are just lists of characters. Just a slip-up.

Answer (score 0):

We have `functools.reduce` for exactly this purpose:

```
In [66]: import functools                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [67]: functools.reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y), '123')                                                                                                                                              
Out[67]: 6

In [68]: functools.reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y), '12345')                                                                                                                                            
Out[68]: 15
```

Comment: Never heard of this function before. Thank you. Albeit it didn't get me to the targeted computing-time, but still helpfull.